# Administrating oracle database 11g - new database, user and tables

Tags: database, oracle-11g

i've installed oracle database 11g standard edition. I opened "Oracle Enterprise manager" and i want to made new (and empty) database, create 5 tables and a user with permission only do access this one db. 
i'm new in oracle db, and wasted already 2 days on trying to figure out how to use it - no success :(

I need some tips how to do it i cant fint anything in EM, so much options, everything useless.

Is there any other tool to manage db like phpmyadmin on mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Two days would be a long time to get started with a new email program or web browser, but it is expected for an Oracle database.  It may not be reasonable or desirable, but we can't do much about that.  So, take a step back and work your way into the product.  Standard Edition is just as difficult as the full blown Enterprise Edition.  You will have a lot to learn and it is not your fault that certain aspects of Oracle don't make much sense.

I suggest you start off by reading the [Oracle concepts guide](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/portal.portal_db?selected=11&frame=).  Then look through the appropriate [platform installation guides](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/portal.portal_db?selected=11&frame=).  If your database is already installed and working you can install [SQLDeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) to build your tables and set permissions or do it all from [SQLPlus](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604.pdf).

Comment: You forget the "2 day DBA" documentation from Oracle: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/toc.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you have `$ORACLE_HOME/bin` in your `$PATH`, and X11 working, you can say `dbca` on the box you have the Oracle server installed and get a wizard for DB creation.

Grid Control is for monitoring/managing existing systems, not for creating new ones.

Comment: OS specific, but useful if applicable.

Comment: DBCA is also in the Start menu on Windows